# Combine like JSON properties and sum values

Tags: javascript, json

I've got something like this:

```
[
    {
        "SalesRep": "Bob",
        "Market": "Market1",
        "Revenue": "1000"
    },
    {
        "SalesRep": "Mary",
        "Market": "Market2",
        "Revenue": "2000"
    },
    {
        "SalesRep": "Amy",
        "Market": "Market1",
        "Revenue": "3000"
    },
    {
        "SalesRep": "Cody",
        "Market": "Market2",
        "Revenue": "5000"
    }
]
```

and what I'm trying to get is another object that combines like markets and sums the revenue so the above would be :

```
[
    {
        "Market": "Market1",
        "Revenue": "4000"
    },
    {
        "Market": "Market2",
        "Revenue": "7000"
    }
]
```

I can't figure out how to iterate over `topMarkets` to search if the Market exist inside. I've tried many different things, but this is probably the closest I've come.

```
var topMarkets = [];
$.each( data, function( k, v ) {

    for(var i=0; i<data.length; i++) {
         if (topMarkets.length == 0) {
             topMarkets.push({"Market":v.Market, "Revenue":parseFloat(v.Revenue)});
         } else {
             //how to check if topMarkets[i]["Market"] == v.Market ?
             //push to topMarkets here if v.Market does not exist in topMarkets
         }
    }

});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just got to iterate and check!

```
var totalRevenues = [];
for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
    var market = data[i].Market;
    var index = getMarketIndex(totalRevenues, market);
    var revenue = parseInt(data[i].Revenue, 10);

    if (index != -1) {  
        totalRevenues[index].Revenue += revenue;
    } else {
        totalRevenues.push({Market: market, Revenue: revenue});
    }
}

function getMarketIndex(array, market) {
    for (var i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
        if (array[i].Market == market) {
            return i;
        }
    }

    return -1;
}
```

Working demo: http://jsfiddle.net/hcgawe3p/